# Subtlety with order of partial derivatives and absolute continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory

Let $f(x,y)$ be a real-valued function on an $2$ dimensional open set $U$ such that:

1. $f$ is smooth in $x$ for each fixed $y$ and all partial derivatives w.r.t $x$ are absolutely continuous w.r.t $y$ for each fixed $x$.
2. $\partial_y f$ exists everywhere and is smooth on $U$.

Then, $\partial_y \partial_x f$ exists a.e on $U$ while $\partial_x \partial_y f$ exists everywhere on $U$ and in fact is smooth.

Now, my question is that do these two partial derivatives coincide a.e?

This seems like a quite subtle problem..Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left|{#1}\right|}\def\lim{\mathop{\mathrm{lim}}\limits}\newcommand{\bc}[1]{{\left\{{#1}\right\}}}$I think this is the case and it's easy to prove, but I may be missing something.

Since $\partial_x f(x, \cdot)$ is absolutely continuous, $\partial_y \partial_x f(x, \cdot)$ exists a.e. and is defined by
$$\int_{y_0}^{y_1} \partial_y \partial_x f(x, y) \, dy = \partial_x f(x, y_1) - \partial_x f(x, y_0)$$
for every $y_0 < y_1$ such that $\{x\} \times [y_0, y_1] \subset U$.

So proving that $\partial_y \partial_x f(x, \cdot) = \partial_x \partial_y f(x, \cdot)$ holds a.e. is equivalent to showing that
$$\int_{y_0}^{y_1} \partial_x \partial_y f(x, y) \, dy = \partial_x f(x, y_1) - \partial_x f(x, y_0)$$
holds for every $y_0 < y_1$ such that $\{x\} \times [y_0, y_1] \subset U$.

Now $\partial_x \partial_y f(x, y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\partial_y f(x + h, y) - \partial_y f(x, y)}h$ and this is dominated by $\phi(y)$ continuous, hence integrable on $[y_0, y_1]$ since $\partial_y f$ is smooth by assumption. Therefore we can use the dominated convergence theorem to get
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{y_0}^{y_1} \partial_x \partial_y f(x, y) \, dy
&= \int_{y_0}^{y_1} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\partial_y f(x + h, y) - \partial_y f(x, y)}h \, dy \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{y_0}^{y_1} \frac{\partial_y f(x + h, y) - \partial_y f(x, y)}h \, dy \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \bc{ \frac{f(x+h,y_1) - f(x,y_1)}h - \frac{f(x+h,y_0) - f(x,y_0)}h } \\
&= \partial_x f(x, y_1) - \partial_x f(x, y_0),
\end{align*}$$
as desired.